# Gitlab repository main page failing to update mirror of master branch

Tags: git, gitlab

My GitLab repository's main page is failing (for months now) to mirror the master branch:

[image]

I have no problems pushing and pulling changes to the master branch, so I'm wondering why this error is occurring. Should I worry about this, and is there a solution to remove the error?

Answer (score 0):

The only condition for having the mirror to work properly is that you don't push code to your mirrored master branch. Therefore, if your mirror isn't updating, I suggest:

- turn off mirroring
- turn on again
- don't push to remote master

Ref https://about.gitlab.com/2016/12/01/how-to-keep-your-fork-up-to-date-with-its-origin/#comment-3030417153

Let me know if this helps :)